# Problems with special (composite) characters when uploading files

Tags: php, html

I'm uploading files with names which include special characters, through a form. It seems that somehow, when the files are sent, the name is changed.

This is problematic for me since I want to check the given names against a predetermined list.  Everything works fine as long as no special (composite) characters like å/ä/ö are used. How can I solve this problem?

The form:

```
<form name="uploadForm" id="uploadForm" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <label class="upload" for="upload">Choose file(s) to upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="upload[]" id="upload" accept=".m4a" multiple required> 
    <button type="submit" name='submit' id="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Uploading a file called 'rör.m4a' through the above form, I get the following in php:

```
echo bin2hex($_FILES['upload']['name'][0]); => 726fcc88722e6d3461 

echo bin2hex('rör.m4a'); => 72c3b6722e6d3461
```

The upload seems to affect the composite character 'ö'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did a quick test and it works as expected for me. Whenever I run into a problem with characters that aren't in the ASCII set I immediately go to the bytes to see what's actually in there, don't trust your eyes or what the debugger tells you. Try running `echo bin2hex($_FILES['upload']['name'][0])` and comparing that to `echo bin2hex('rör.m4a')` to see what your machine tells you.

Comment: Thanks :) I get different hexadecimal outputs for `$_FILES['upload']['name'][0]` and `rör.m4a`. Even when there is nothing but the above code on the page.

Comment: Can you edit your post above with those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want intl's [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer).

Notes:

- `FORM_C` is the default, included for reference
- `json_encode()` used only for the fact that it escapes unicode for easy viewing.

```php
$input = 'rör.m4a';

var_dump(
    json_encode(Normalizer::normalize($input, Normalizer::FORM_C)),
    json_encode(Normalizer::normalize($input, Normalizer::FORM_D))
);
```

Output:

```
string(14) ""r\u00f6r.m4a""
string(15) ""ro\u0308r.m4a""
```

Beyond simply comparing filenames, you should take special care with which normalization format you use with which filesystem. Eg: ext4 doesn't care and will create 2 files with seemingly identical filenames, whereas whichever FS Mac uses will only use the decomposed format, and silently convert composed characters.